# Regular expression group/substitution question

Tags: regex

I have the following two regular expressions. My goal is to extract everything after "EX"

Example 1:

```
(^[EX]{2})(\w+)
```

Example data

```
EX12456
```

https://regex101.com/r/6QqHwf/13

Match Information shows Group 2 is the data I want and matches the SUBSTITUTION $2.

Example 2:

```
(?<=EX)(?s)(.*$)
```

Example data

```
123456/stackoverflo@|EX789
```

https://regex101.com/r/6QqHwf/12

Match Information shows Group 1 is the data I want, but DOESN'T match the SUBSTITUTION $1.

How can I extra/put date "789" into the SUBSTITUTION?  Thanks!!!

Comment: The "substitution" removes what's matched, and ignored what's left behind. Your original regex would match `EX` and allow it to be removed, but your second regex does *not* match `123456/stackoverflo@|EX`, so it is not removed. Try `.*(?<=EX)(?s)(.*$)` instead - this matches the first part of the string and lets you remove it. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6QqHwf/14)

Comment: @NickReed Thanks!!!! Just curious, does .* mean match everything until EX?

Comment: See answer for explanation; `.` means "any character" and `*` is "0 or more times" - it matches the whole string and then backtracks to make sure your lookbehind matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "substitution" removes what's matched, and ignored what's left behind. Your original regex would match `EX` and allow it to be removed, but your second regex does not match `123456/stackoverflo@|EX`, so it is not removed. Try `.*(?<=EX)(?s)(.*$)` instead - this matches the first part of the string and lets you remove it.

Note that `.*` matches the entire string - however, the lookbehind `(<=EX)` then forces it to give up part of the match in order to satisfy the constraints. (`.*` means "any character except newlines, repeated zero or more times.")

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6QqHwf/14)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extract everything after `EX` you don't have to use any capturing group and can use a [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<=`.

**Note** that `[EX]` is a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which will match either E or X

```
(?<=EX).*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SxR2d9/1)

In the second pattern is only a single match which is group 1. If you replace with group 1 you will end up with the same start value.

What you could do if there is only a single occurrence of `EX` is to match it and use group 1 (For example `$1`) in the replacement so the match will not be part of the result.

```
^.*EX(.*$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bw4CL9/1)